# Using c++ to solve wordsearch.

Tags: c++, wordsearch

Sorry to bother everyone with a simple question but I'm very new at C++ and i don't know what to do. So I've been given a framework in C++ that reads in 2 txt files containing a wordsearch and a list of words to be found and present the results in another txt file. 
I'm trying to complete the framework but I cant figure out how exactly the program will check all 8 directions or how a system will compare the words in the dictionary file with the wordsearch and put any matched words into the results.txt file. I've attached the framework below and any info or advice on how to get started would be deeply appreciated.

```
dictionary.txt 
ABSEIL
BIKE
PIXEL
RESIGHTS
YARDWORKS

wordsearch.txt 
S T H G I S E R B
G K L L B X D I E
K P R H I M K L D
T G Y O L E X I P
B A P T W H T E J
T Q U D X D W S F
V M V S H L R B A
H Q L B C K S A Y
R D G B F J P Q Y


Wordsearch.h 
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class WordSearch
{
 public:
WordSearch();
~WordSearch();

bool ReadPuzzle();
bool ReadDictionary();
bool SolvePuzzleWithDictionary();

void WriteResults(string fileName);

private:
LARGE_INTEGER start, end, frequency;
const int NUMBER_OF_RUNS;
const string PUZZLE_NAME;
const string DICTIONARY_NAME;
};


Wordsearch.cpp 
 #include "WordSearch.h"
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

WordSearch::WordSearch() : NUMBER_OF_RUNS(500), PUZZLE_NAME("wordsearch_grid.txt"), DICTIONARY_NAME("dictionary.txt")
{
}

WordSearch::~WordSearch()
{
}

bool WordSearch::ReadPuzzle()
{
cout << endl << "ReadPuzzle() has NOT been implemented" << endl;
return true;
}

bool WordSearch::ReadDictionary()
{
cout << endl << "ReadDictionary() has NOT been implemented" << endl;
return true;
}

bool WordSearch::SolvePuzzleWithDictionary() {
cout << endl << "SolvePuzzleWithDictionary() has NOT been implemented" << endl;
double timeTakenInSeconds;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

for (int n = 0; n < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; ++n) {
    // Add solving code here!
}

QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
timeTakenInSeconds = (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double)(frequency.QuadPart*NUMBER_OF_RUNS);

cout << fixed << setprecision(10) << "SolvePuzzleWithDictionary() - " << timeTakenInSeconds << " seconds" << endl;
return false;
}

void WordSearch::WriteResults(string fileName) {
cout << "WriteResults() has NOT been implemented" << endl;
}
```

Comment: As a hint, if you have an array of strings corresponding to the rows then the normal horizontal search is trivial. So you could apply a similar logic to the other directions too: construct string arrays for reverse horizontal, vertical etc. This will be fast for word searching at the expense of set up cost.

Comment: I think I would use a matrix approach (especially if you need to search diagonal patterns). Find the starting letter then look at all adjacent letters for a match, move to that (x,y) and do the same thing until you have a complete match. Not sure if that would be the fastest, might be better to start out looking for a complete match horizontally and vertically first (kind of like what Bathsheba suggested) then (if not found) move to the more complex search.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have an array of index increments for moving in all directions (provided that you store your field in a matrix), so you could write generic code for trying all directions:

```
const int dirIncr[][2] = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}/*...*/}
```

so you loop through all possible start cells and from each sell search in all possible directions (and on each step you have to check if current coordinates still fit into your array).

As for actual search [Prefix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be helpful here.